# Split / combine a larger printed circuit board from smaller boards

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I have plans for a large PCB (~12".) Some sections of this board are modular - they have a very similar design. To lower the price, is it feasible to split one big board into smaller, modular parts? Is there an established method for combining smaller boards into a larger unit (in the same plane,) both mechanically and electronically?

Comment: This is typically how its done anyway. You order a set of boards and they are panelized (multiple put on one large board), then it is all etched and sometimes assembled before being snapped at V-scores or cut by a milling machine.

Comment: Please provide some more information about the sections of your PCB that you want to be part of such a workflow. What is the power/voltage/frequency requirements of your board? Application? Why design a large PCB (12") in the first place? As posed, this question can have many answers. You can modularize power supplies relatively easily or change interfaces depending on product segments. Kindly edit your post further to include this info.

Answer (score 0):

PCB manufacturers understand immediately how many different PCB's are in your panel.

Just be sincere and you'll get the cheapest price.